# looking to integrate R-trees into AlchemyDB

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis

I am the author of AlchemyDB: http://code.google.com/p/alchemydatabase/

I would very much like to add geospatial indexing in the form of R-trees (most likely).

Are there any C/C++ packages that have simple stripped down R-trees?

I am a big fan of small codebases that are easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

You might look at libspatialindex - http://libspatialindex.github.com/ , it seems to have decent documentation.